# ARM Template - Conditionally add to an Array

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {        
        "externalSubnet1": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "SQLServerName": "someName",
        "SQLDatabaseName": "someDatabase",
        "Subnet1": "/subscriptions/771adxxx-xxxx-xxxx-9xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/some_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/some_vnet/subnets/some_subnet1",
        "Subnet2": "/subscriptions/771adxxx-xxxx-xxxx-9xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/some_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/some_vnet/subnets/some_subnet1",
    },
    "resources": [{
            "name": "[variables('SQLServerName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "location": "Central US",
            "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "Logical SQL Server"
            },
            "kind": "v12.0",
            "properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "xyz",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "xyz",
                "version": "12.0"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/virtualNetworkRules",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                    "name": "x1",
                    "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('SQLServerName'))]"],
                    "properties": {
                        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[parameters('externalSubnet1')]",
                        "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": false
                    }
                }, {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/virtualNetworkRules",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                    "name": "x2",
                    "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('SQLServerName'))]"],
                    "properties": {
                        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[variables('Subnet1')]",
                        "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": false
                    }
                }, {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/virtualNetworkRules",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                    "name": "x3",
                    "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('SQLServerName'))]"],
                    "properties": {
                        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[variables('Subnet2')]",
                        "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the following ARM template. In the innermost resources array there are 3 virtual network rules. What I want is that if the value of the parameter `externalSubnet1` is there i.e. it is non blank string then I want the first element of the resources array to be included. This makes sense because the variable `externalSubnet1` needs to be a valid subnet id (something similar to variables `Subnet1` or `Subnet2`) otherwise the deployment fails.

What I tried?

I looked at [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/conditional-resource-deployment) but it is at resource level so can't use that.

I also looked at [if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical#if) but the problem is that it still includes that JSON block in the array with a blank virtualNetworkSubnetId and that also fails. I want the entire first element (JSON block) of the virtualNetworkRules resource array to be excluded i.e. there should be only 2 elements in the array when the parameter `externalSubnet1` is empty string.

So, how can we achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: So your real template has 3 parameters, one for each rule?

Comment: No, real template only has 1 parameter as defined in the question above. If it has a value then first element of the array should be included but if it's blank then it shouldn't be included.

Comment: What should the condition be for the other two rules then?

Comment: X2 and x3 will always be there. They are hard coded subnets and must be added all the time irrespective of what parameters are passed to the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I Understand it correctly then ***you want to conditionally execute the `VirtualNetworkRule`*** depending on the ***string parameter externalsubnet1*** . If parameter ***value is present then `x1` will be executed*** and if ***value is blank then `x2` and `x3` will be executed***. In that case you can use the below template:

**Template:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {        
        "externalSubnet1": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "SQLServerName": "ansserver",
        "Subnet1": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/ansumantest/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/ansuman-vnet/subnets/default",
        "Subnet2": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/ansumantest/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/ansuman-vnet/subnets/subnet1"
    },
    "resources": [{
            "name": "[variables('SQLServerName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "location": "East US",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "ansuman",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "password",
                "version": "12.0",
                "publicNetworkAccess":"Enabled"
            },
            "resources": [
                {   
                    "condition":"[not(empty(parameters('externalSubnet1')))]",
                    "type": "virtualNetworkRules",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('SQLServerName'),'test1')]",
                    "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('SQLServerName'))]"],
                    "properties": {
                        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[parameters('externalSubnet1')]",
                        "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": false
                    }
                }, {
                    "condition":"[empty(parameters('externalSubnet1'))]",
                    "type": "virtualNetworkRules",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('SQLServerName'),'test2')]",
                    "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('SQLServerName'))]"],
                    "properties": {
                        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[variables('Subnet1')]",
                        "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": false
                    }
                }, {
                    "condition":"[empty(parameters('externalSubnet1'))]",
                    "type": "virtualNetworkRules",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('SQLServerName'),'test3')]",
                    "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('SQLServerName'))]"],
                    "properties": {
                        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[variables('Subnet2')]",
                        "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually x2 and x3 are not dependent on the parameter but that's ok, I am going to try this now and get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks it did work as expected. Looks like I assumed that condition only applies at the root level of the array i.e either all 3 or nothing.